# Is it possible to solve this problem mathematically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

[image]

On this day, after a total of $4-5$ hours, the following conclusion I reached: This is impossible.

> I think there's not a "special" way to do it.I don't even know where to start. I really want to know if at least this is possible or impossible.

Comment: Worst case scenario you could exhaust all possibilities with a computer. So yes, it can be solved. There should be a more obvious method :) I'll think about it.

Comment: Now, this _looks_ like a division problem to me, but I am unfamiliar with exactly which term goes where

Comment: You've added the tag modular-arithmetic so presumably there is some extra context here you have not explained properly.

Comment: @James Arathoon Should I delete this tag?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the number of stars! You are going to divide by $****7*$ and end up with $**7**$, so the big number should be $(****7*)\times (**7**)$. The smallest the latter value can be is $100070\times 10700=10077049000$, but this has eleven digits whereas $**7*******$ has eleven digits. Do you allow $*$ to be zero as well?

Comment: Is it base 10 arithmetic?

Comment: @Mathematician42 I think, no.

Comment: @James Arathoon Yes, definitely..

Comment: Well in that case we have an answer right? But then you can ask this question again with one extra star. Then we probably have to do some arithmetic. In that case it's probably a good idea to work backwards.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I think you made a mistake in the computation somewhere, $100070 \times 10700 = 1070749000$, which has only 10 digits. So maybe there is a solution.

Comment: Seven times the number has six digits, so it is less than 142858; but other multiples of the number have seven digits, so it is at least 111112

Comment: One of the seven-digit multiples has either 9 or 0 in the second digit; but 142857*9 is less than 1900000 so the second digit of that multiple is 0.

Comment: @Reinier: You are absolutely right! I added a zero somewhere.

Comment: You say that there is no "problem"  in the question? And this is solvable?

Comment: Is the remainder at the end of the division zero?

Comment: Yes,@Upax you are right.

Comment: In this case it is possible to work backward.

Comment: This link http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/4.pdf credits the puzzle to EH Berwick, published in 1906 in 'The School World'

Comment: ~Michael that could be an snwer, right? The linked pdf has a solution.

Comment: @Michael thank you so much.!!

Answer (score 3):

My calculations below are not perfectly checked, but they seem to be fine.

```
**7******* ****7*
******     **7**
------
****7**
*******
-------
00*7****
  *7****
--------
  *******
  ****7**
---------
  00******
    ******
    ------

===================

Since at the third step we subtract ****7* 
multiplied by 7 and this product still has 
six digits, the first digit of ****7* is 1.
Thus the first digit in all seven-digital 
products of ****7* is 1 too.

**7******* 1***7*
******     **7**
------
****7**
1******
-------
00*7****
  *7****
--------
  *******
  1***7**
---------
  001*****
    1*****
    ------

===================

Since 199999x9=1799991, taking into account 
the double zeroes, we obtain additional 1's

**7******* 1***7*
******     **7**
------
1***7**
1******
-------
00*7****
  *7****
--------
  1******
  1***7**
---------
  001*****
    1*****
    ------

===================

Looking at the last step multiplier of 1***7*,
we see that it is 1x1***7* 

**7******* 1***7*
******     **7*1
------
1***7**
1******
-------
00*7****
  *7****
--------
  1******
  1***7**
---------
  001***7*
    1***7*
    ------

===================

Since 9x1***7*>=1000700, 1***7*>=1000700/9>111188, so 1***7*>=111270.

If 7x1***7*=97**** then *7****-97****=1*****, a contradiction. 

Assume that 7x1***7*=77****. Then 1***7*<=779999/7<111429 and 1***7*<=111379.
Since 8x111379<1000000, the second and the forth digits in **7*1 are 9, so  
9x111*7*=100*7**. Since 9x111270=1001430 and 9x111379=1002411, 
we have 9x111*7*=10017**, so 111300=1001700/9<=111*7*<=1001799/9=111311,
a contradiction.

So 7x1***7*=87****. Since 00*7****-87****=1*****, 00*7****=0097****,
and 00*7****-87****=10****. Since 10*****>=1***7**, 1***7**=10**7** 

Also 1***7*>870000/7>124285.
But 9x124285=1118565>10**7**, so the forth digit in **7*1 is 8. 


**7******* 125*7*
******     **781
------
1***7**
1******
-------
0097****
  87****
--------
  10*****
  10**7**
---------
  00125*7*
    125*7*
    ------

===================


Now we shall consecutively tighten the bounds.  

Since 125087<1000700/8<125*7*<879999/7 <125714, 125170<=125*7*<=125679.
8x125170=1001360, 8x125679=1005432, so 1001700<=8x125*7*=10**7**<=1004799.
Since 125212<1001700/8<125*7*<1004799/8<125600, 125270<=125*7*<=125579.
8x125270=1002160, 8x125579=1004632, so 1002700<=8x125*7*=10**7**<=1003799. 
Since 125337<1002700/8<125*7*<1003799/8<125474, 125370<=125*7*<=125474.
8x125370=1002960, 8x125474=1003792, so 1003700<=8x125*7*=10037**<=1003792. 
Since 125462<1003700/8<125*7*, 125470<=125*7*.
8x125470=1003760, so 1003760<=8x125*7*=10037**<=1003792.

**7******* 12547*
******     **781
------
1***7**
1******
-------
0097****
  87****
--------
  10*****
  10037**
---------
  0012547*
    12547*
    ------

===================

Since 

7781x125474=976313194<1***7*****, the second digit in **781 is 8 or 9. 

Since 

8781x125470=1101752070
8781x125474=1101787194
9781x125470=1227222070
9781x125474=1227261194

8 is the only possibility.

Since  

18781x125470=2356452070
18781x125474=2356527194
28781x125470=3611152070
28781x125474=3611267194
38781x125470=4865852070
38781x125474=4866007194
48781x125470=6120552070
48781x125474=6120747194
58781x125470=7375252070
58781x125474=7375487194
68781x125470=8629952070
68781x125474=8630227194
78781x125470=9884652070
78781x125474=9884967194

*8781=58781

Finally,

7375252070 125470  7375310851 125471  7375369632 125472  7375428413 125473  7375487194 125474
627350     58781   627355     58781   627360     58781   627365     58781   627370     58781
------             ------             ------             ------             ------
1101752            1101760            1101769            1101778            1101787
1003760            1003768            1003776            1003784            1003792
-------            -------            -------            -------            -------
00979920           00979928           00979936           00979944           00979951
  878290             878297             878304             878311             878318
--------           --------           --------           --------             ------
  1016307            1016315            1016323            1016331            1016339
  1003760            1003768            1003776            1003784            1003792
---------          ---------          ---------          ---------            -------
  00125470           00125471           00125472           00125473           00125474
    125470             125471             125472             125473             125474
    ------             ------             ------             ------             ------
```

Answer (score 1):

**I took the puzzle with the constraint that all the 7's are already written on the paper, and that no starred number starts with a zero.**

> $7\times d$ has only 6 digits, so $d<142858$.

There are two times when d multiplied by a digit has seven numbers, so
$8\times d>1000000$ ($d>125000$). So far, $d=1***7*$.

> From the 00*7 that is in the middle, we know that the star must be a 9, and that $7\times d$ starts with $87****$ so the difference (from $97****$) starts with $10****$ and from this, we know that $q=**78*$ and that $d<125714$ ($7\times d<879999$)

Assuming that no other 7 can be written, 8*d has a 7 in second digit, while 9*d has no 7 in it, so $q=*978*$.

> $8\times d$ : $10**7**$ and $125070<d<125679$, we can check manually that ($d=125470, d=125471, d=125472, d=125473$ or $d=125474$) are the only solutions that make $8\times d$ in the right form.

With this, only $d=125470$ and $d=125474$ allow $9\times d$ : $1******$ without any other seven. Putting the numbers back in, we quickly reach an impossibility with the "seven minus seven" when we substract $7*d$.

> So, I discarded my solution without any extra Seven, and went on the path that Alex Ravsky has just posted - now I am upvoting his solution, without rewriting it.

Comment: You say: *"There are two times when d multiplied by a digit has seven numbers, so 8 x d > 1000000"*. But couldn't both multiplications be with the same digit, 9? (and thus d be > 111111)?

Comment: Given my hypothesis that all the 7's are already written, the numbers are different, so one is $8\times d$ and the other is $9\times d$.

Comment: I don't get why you assume that all numbers are different. I see lots of same (7s) in the known digits.